# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rospkg'

Tags: python, ros, rospy, cmakelists-options

I am new to ROS,

I have a problem when I import rospy into my script file example.py and run it: It says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nagarjunv/hk_ws/src/rvo/src/example.py", line 4, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 52, in <module>
    import roslib
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from roslib.launcher import load_manifest  # noqa: F401
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>
    import rospkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rospkg'
```

I am importing the following into my script file:The line 4 is rospy

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import rospy
```

THis is my CmakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(rvo)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES rvo
  CATKIN_DEPENDS rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

This is my package xml:

```
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>message_generation</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
```

I specify both in CMakelists and Package XML  'rospy' and importing it. I also checked my ros has rospy package available. BUt, I dont understand why I am having trouble running my script file?

```
rosrun rvo example.py
```

I will be glad to provide more details about this error. Can any please let me know the solution to this problem?

Comment: If my answer solved you problem, please mark it as such. Otherwise do provide more info.

Comment: @Nagarjun Vinukonda How did you solve issue?

Answer (score 7):

Try to change the shebang (line 1) according to the python version your ROS distro works with.

For melodic or earlier: `#!/usr/bin/env python2`

For noetic or later: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your ROS version and respectively the one of `rospkg` you may need to stick to python 2.x or 3.x.

Your script is calling `python3` interpreter

> #!/usr/bin/env **python3**

but you can clearly see in the error log that a different version is used by your installation:

> File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/**python2.7**/dist-packages/rospy/**init**.py",
> line 49, in 
> from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \

If you want to use Python 3 for a ROS installation that is based on Python 2.7 you need to build everything from scratch but even then the chances for success are pretty slim.

Here are some possible solution:

- If you want to use Python 3, see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/UsingPython3). According to this article ROS Noetic is targeting only Python 3.
- If you don't want to upgrade, you need to stick to Python 2.7.
- If the version of Python is of no concern, just adapt your script to use the one your ROS installation is depending on.